# How to remove workflow associations/subscriptions

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, csom

Is there any method available in CSOM to delete workflow subscription from site. I tried with `WorkflowDeploymentServiceDef.DeleteObject()` and `WorkflowDeploymentServiceDef.RemoveFromParentCollection()` but its giving error like method is not supported.